# React / NextJS I18next translation issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

When using https://www.i18next.com/ translation module default values of texts are still being shown on first load for a split second even thought I'm using  functionality in _app.js.

Does anyone know how to solve the translations so they don't show before they aren't loaded I thought that Suspense will do that...

My index file:

```
  i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "GB",
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/assets/locales/{{lng}}/translations.json",
    },
  });
```

_app.js file:

```
<Suspense fallback=""> <Component {...pageProps} /></Suspense>
```

Comment: i18n.init() is a promise, you could await it. before start the app

Comment: how do you do that? Putting await before this does not work... Do I need to nest it with .then() ?

Comment: 1 extract that initialization into another file. 2 wrapp your code with: export default init = async () => { await i18n.use(..).init(..) }.  3 in your index.js  import init18n from './path/to/thenewfile'; and find the place where you want to call await init18n()

Comment: are you using next-i18next?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?